# Как запускать tomcat из под другого пользователя

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, vds

https://andreyex.ru/ubuntu/ustanovit-tomcat-9-na-ubuntu-16-04-vps/

Установил по гайду tomcat на vds. В гайде, в одном из пунктов написано создать отдельного пользователя для безопасности, а дальше он запускает tomcat не через sh скрипты, а через Systemd.
Я так и не понял, как запускать sh скрипты через, созданного мною, пользователя и в чем заключается безопасность?

Comment: Запускайте руками, если этого недостаточно, то не надо писать скрипты для сервиса, там уже должны быть скрипты